# How can I customize a drop-down list form element in django?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am creating an application in django and I have the next problem:

I create a form class in django, as I show here:

```
class A(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
```

This way, the form will show a drop-down list with ALL the elements in the `modelA`, but what I want to do is a filter; I mean, I want the drop-down list not to show ALL the elements. I want to show only the elements in `modelA` which have the value of the `attribute1 = '1'` (`attribute1` is an attribute of `modelA`).

Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: "This way, the form will show a drop-down list with ALL the elements in the modelA" : it won't.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers is correct. This form is to create/edit an instance of `ModelA`. Is this model a ForeignKey in another model perhaps?

Comment: Yes, modelA is a foreign key in another model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what field you want to filter, but you could do it like this:

```
class A(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['your_field'].queryset = self.fields['your_field'].queryset \
                .filter(some_filter_value=1)
```

Comment: After reading the question again I think you mean something different, but will wait for feedback.